# Connection Reset error on Oracle Native connection pool with Spring

Tags: java, oracle, spring, connection-pooling, ojdbc

Am using Oracle Native connection pooling with Spring using Thin jdbc driver and noticing the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:519)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1583)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:515)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.defaultUserPrePopulateCache(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:222)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.<init>(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:198)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheManager.createCache(OracleConnectionCacheManager.java:306)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheManager.createCache(OracleConnectionCacheManager.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.cacheInitialize(OracleDataSource.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:393)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366)
    ... 25 more
```

Here is how the data source is configured in spring configuration file

```
<bean id="datasourceone" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="URL">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xyz-01) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xyz-02) (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ABCD)))</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>XYZ</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>XXXX</value>
    </property>
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <value>
            MinLimit:1
            MaxLimit:5
            InitialLimit:1
            ConnectionWaitTimeout:120
            InactivityTimeout:180
            ValidateConnection:true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Would highly recommend if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same? Would tuning the connection pool help? If yes, is there anything specific that needs to get tuned?

Comment: Try using a different connection pool implementation and check if you see the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different connection pool implementation and check if you see the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the connection string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xyz-01)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xyz-02)(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=on))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ABCD)))
```

and test again.